# sending a mail inside a django view gives NameError

Tags: python, django, django-views, sendmail

Trying to send mail inside django view

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

# Snippet inside a view
for ml in mls:
    try:
        l = Letter.objects.get(pk = ml.message_key)
    except Exception as e:
        mail_txt = _("sending mail failed " + str(e) + " " +  str(ml.activity_org) + " " + str(ml.scheduled_time))
        send_mail(mail_txt, "sending mail", "user@domain.com", ["sender@domain.com"], fail_silently=False)
```

**Error**

```
NameError: global name 'send_mail' is not defined
```

Comment: please provide the full traceback. you are not importng properly the send_email. are you importing it inside your `views.py` ?

Comment: What version of django do you use?

Comment: sorry for posting the question, send_mail, was not defined in another file.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you tu use `EmailMultiAlternatives`. I use this, is easy to configure and use.
Example:

**Add this to Settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'yourmail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpass'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

If you use different mail server change the shown data for your data

---

**Function example**

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
title = 'Test Email'
message_text = 'Test email message'
#email_to has to be a list, even if you're sending mail only to 1 address
mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(title, message_text, 'from@email.com', ['email_to1'])
mail.send()
```

You can attach files, or html code... More info in [Django Documentation - Mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/)

Hope it helps!